# How to add different styles in mobile screen for function created with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using below javascript function to render HTML in a module.

```
function generateHTML(bankName) {
    let content = `<div class="bankName" style=""><strong style="font-size: 28px;font-weight: 600;line-height: 48px;">Thank You!</strong>
    <br /><span style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;"> Your <b>${bankName}
    </b> data has been successfully retrieved.</span></div>
    <style>
    .bankName {
        display: flex;
         flex-direction: column; 
         align-items: center; 
         height: 100%;
         justify-content: center;
         background-color:white;
         text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
        color:rgb(158,158,158);
        
    }

    .bankName strong:after {
        content: '';
        background: rgb(158,158,158);
        height: 1px;
        width: 275px;
        display: block;
        margin-top: 8px;
    }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .bankName {
        justify-content: start;
    }
  }
    </style>
    `;

    return `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html><body>${content}</body></html>`;

}
```

Now, I want to align its text to the top of the screen on mobile devices and in the center on desktop devices, to do so, I added a media query in `style` tag. But that media query property is running on desktops as well. I don't know what is the reason, but it supposes to run only on mobile screens.

If there is any other way to achieve the same results, then I can do that as well.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You might need to include your media query code to the post as well.

Comment: @JoshuaOoi, ok, I will update the post

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `align-items: self-start;` in `@media` instead of `justify-ontent` property, as its `flex-direction` is set to `column`

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .bankName {
        align-items: self-start;
    }
  }
```

Comment: the media query is running on the desktop as well, I am not sure why.

Comment: add important to "align-items: self-start; !important" , above media cannot run on screen with width more than 767px

Comment: also add screenshot of the generated html from this function

Comment: your solution didn't work